Problem integrating SVN repo into Azure DevOps
On Azure DevOps, I create a pipeline and it asks where is your code and I click Subversion. Then I add a subversion repository connection.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Eventually I get to the step where I need to add an Agent pool but it says there are no authorized queues to pick from but there is an agent pool under project settings.
enter image description here
Question is why isn't any agent pool showing up under the drop down menu when creating a pipeline?
I tried using different pipeline templates such as .NET Desktop or Empty pipeline but both need an Agent Pool and in both cases it doesn't show up.

Can you check if your agent pool and Pipeline are in the same project? Or you can try to create a new agent pool in the project and check if you can see it when selecting the agent pool in Pipeline.

Is the agent visible under organization settings, or under project settings? These are different. Agents needs permissions for each project.
To verify this, make sure you're on the project settings https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_settings/agentqueues
and if you do not see the agent here, click on Add pool -> rbExisting and check option "Grant access permission to all pipelines"

My team leader can access agents for the purpose of building pipelines so it seems to be a permission problem.
